# CSS or JS - Hide old elements from html

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a set of paragrapghs in my Ionic 4 project's html file:

```
<! –– page 1 ––>
<p *ngIf="x1">Text 1</p>
<p *ngIf="x2">Text 2</p>
<p *ngIf="x3">Text 3</p>

<! –– page 2 ––>
<p *ngIf="x4">Text 4</p>
<p *ngIf="x5">Text 5</p>
<p *ngIf="x6">Text 6</p>

<! –– page 3... ––>
```

I have a public counter = 0, starting from 0 counting +1 on click.
I am controlling the above paragraphs via ngIf, setting them "true" in ts (if counter = 4, x4=true).

**I want to set up an automated rule, either CSS or ts that limits the number of paragraphs visible on webpage (without setting the paragraphs' ngIf to false).**

Conditions & remarks:
So when x4 is visible, then x1,x2,x3 should not be visible.
Only 3 paragraphs should be visible at the same time with a page rule in mind.
This rule should be applied to all numbers positioning in page (e.g. if counter = 5, x5=true), only x4 and x5 should be visible (x6 = false, while the counter did not reach it).

What would your solution be?

Answer (score 2):

Let's get the paragraphs:

```
var paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll("p");
```

Define a limit of paragraphs:

```
var limit = 10; //You can change this value any time
```

and let's hide paragraphs beyond the limit:

```
for (let index = limit; index < paragraphs.length; index++) {
    paragraphs[index].style.display = "none";
}
```